# How to define an object values as specific type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Imagine that your typescript function receives an object as parameter. Now I'd like to state that any value is of type `string`. So the idea is to treat the object as a `Map` but without the bound to their type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
function f<T>(o: { [key: string]: T }) {
    console.log(o);
}

f<number>({a: 1, b: 3}) // ok
f<string>({a: 'aa'}) // ok
f<string>({a: 'aa', b: 132}) // error - Property 'b' is incompatible with index signature.
```

For more details - check the documentation on [Index types and string index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)